# play framework or Scala persistency layer to protect concurrent update

Tags: scala, playframework, persistence

The question is about how to solve concurrency issue in Scala. Our current project is based on Spring/Hibernate. Normally, we start up several registry systems and our approach is domain-driven-design so Hibernate optimistic locking guarantees that there is no concurrent update for our domain model.

So if we plan to use play framework or any other persistence api like anorm/slick in the future. Is there any approach in Scala can make sure the domain model is not concurrently updated when several registry systems start up.

Comment: This feature is not implemented yet. There is an issue for slick https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/378. So you have to do optimistic update by your self.

Comment: I think you're mixing two different things. Programming language (Scala) and database locking. They have nothing to do with each other. Scala runs on JVM and so you can use Hibernate in your persistence layer while implementing business logic in Scala for example.